# Unable to import data collector template into Perfmon in Win 2008 but works on Win 7

Tags: perfmon

I created the xml template for Perfmon on Win 7. I was able to import it and run it -all fine.
Now when I copy this xml over to a Win 2008 R2 machine and try to import it into perfmon, I get an error reading "The file specified does not contain valid XML".
The XML is just fine - I checked it in an editor as well.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Try this, open the template file and change

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
```

to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

and try again.  You may want to remove the security element as well just in case.